# In nodejs how to set Mutators like laravel?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to change data like this,

name = 'amit'         // data get from database

name = 'Amit'         // after set mutators like this

[laravel mutators link](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators)

I will try into my model:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let adminSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    email:{
        type:String
    },
    password:{
        type:String
    },
    });

let admin=module.exports=mongoose.model('Admin',adminSchema);

admin.getName = function(namedata)
{
    console.log(namedata);
    name = namedata;
}
module.exports = admin
```

but it's not working.

any another way to do this, please help

Comment: How about https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/getters-setters.html

Comment: this is useful, not exactly solve my problem